# Allow tinymce in WYSIWYG to load different skins per content type

Tags: wysiwyg

I want to user a different default tinymce editor styles per content type. I basically want to use a different default font in the editor area of tinymce per content type.

I have discovered that the editor of tinymce has some default settings that are not configurable through the WYSIWYG module, but it can by modifying the file
jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css

However, that would apply to all content types.

Is there a way to set a skin for a content type?

This would be a start, but does not apply it per content type:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter().
 */
function custom_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'tinymce') { 
  $settings['skin'] = 'o2k7';
  $settings['skin_variant'] = 'silver';
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you've looked through the $context and $settings variables for something related to content type?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, but from memory, I don't think you'll have info about the content type or the node form in the $settings and $context variables, As Darvanen suggests.

I'd implement hook_form_alter() to match node forms, then read the content type being used, and store it as a static variable through drupal_static() function. That way you can access the content type info from the snippet you pasted above, using that same drupal_static() function, and then choose which skin to use.

Comment: Sounds good, but my coding skills are a bit too limited for your solution, sorry :-(